# Imitate keytouch

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I created a keypad from buttons (so an xml with button 1, button 2, etc., but now I want an edit text to react the same as using the soft-keyboard, is there a way to imitate the keypad that comes with the device?

Comment: Just update the edittext using setText() in the onClick() method of your buttons

Comment: But what if someone clicks in the middle of the text to edit it halfway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if (hasFocus) {

      //show your custom keypad
       }
   } 
});
```

Force softkeypad to appear.

```
 EditText yourEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)          getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
 imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```